# "Take Photo" is not showing in CNContact iOS 11

Tags: ios11, cncontactviewcontroller

I have a UIButton name as "Add new contact", When I click on this, a new contact screen is opened but when I tap on "Add Photo" then only "Choose Photo" is coming and "Take Photo" is not coming in iOS 11.
The code for new contact is -

```
let con = CNContact()
    let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: con)
    vc.delegate = self
    let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: have u checked this in real device ? I think for simulator it should not show but for device it should work.

Comment: I checked it in only real device.

Comment: Doe anyone have an answer to this?